# Get a random column from R matrix

Tags: r

In R language, I defined a matrix this way:

```
data <- matrix(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), nrow = 2)
```

This gives me something like this:

```
"A" | "C" | "E"
"B" | "D" | "F"
```

now, How do I get a random column of the matrix?

If I do:

```
sample(x = data, n = 2)
```

I get random elements from all around the matrix, like "A" and "F". What I want is to get a column like "A" and "B", or "C" and "D" or "E" and "F"

I am new to R so any help is really apreciated

Comment: By selecting a column - `data[, sample(1:ncol(data),1) ]` - a `matrix` is just a `vector` with dimensions specified so selecting from `data` just returns individual cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
f <- function(mat) {
    j <- sample(seq_len(ncol(mat)), size=1)
    ## (Use `drop=FALSE` to say "don't convert 1-column matrices to vectors")
    data[, j, drop=FALSE]
}

## Try it out
f(data)
#      [,1]
# [1,] "E" 
# [2,] "F"
```